# Program order in concurrent piece of code

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

Given this piece of code:

```
int x = 0;
co x:= x + 1 || x := x - 1 oc
```

Apparently the possible values are `x = {0, -1, 1}`.

I tried to understand how that can happen and I read about atomic statements which when they happen only they happen.

In the book the example is given that we can break apart the statement `x := x + 1` into atomic statements like.

`READ X (R1) INC WRITE`(W1)

and

`x := x - 1`
into:

`READ X (R2) DEC WRITE` (W2)

and it says that `INC WRITE` and `READ inc` both behave as if atomic and I really don't understand why it is safe to make that assumption?

Then, apparently this program order returns the value `-1` : `R1 -> R2 -> W1 -> W2` which I don't get why?

To my understanding, it seems we are reading the value of value of `x` then reading it again then incrementing it by one and then decrementing it by one and shouldn't that be equal to `0`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with concurrency is that you cannot control the order of concurrent access. So we make the following assumptions:
- x is a global var accessed by the different threads
- x++ and x-- are performed by independent threads.

As indicated in you book, executing a read-modify-write on a shared var is a three step process:
1/ read var into processor reg
2/ modify processor reg
3/ write processor reg to register
Each of these individual actions correspond to a processor instruction and hence are *atomic*. But the global read-modify-write operation is not and can be split by other concurrent actions.

Now consider the concurrent operations

```
 Thread A                          Thread B
 1/ read x->regA                   a/ read x->regB
 2/ regA++                         b/ regB-- 
 3/ write regA->x                  c/ write regB
```

Within a thread the action order 123 or abc will respected, but between Threads A and B any relative order is possible.

With 123abc we have the expected result. x is changed to 1 by thread A, then read by threadB, decremented and finally x=0
It is the same for abc123

But other ordering will conduct to different results.
For instance : 1a2b3c

```
 Thread A                          Thread B
 1/ read x->regA=0                   
                                   a/ read x->regB=0
 2/ regA++=1                       
                                   b/ regB--=-1 
 3/ write regA->x=1
                                   c/ write regB->x=-1
```

And finally x=-1.

But with order 1abc23, we will get x=1.

```
 Thread A                          Thread B
 1/ read x->regA=0                   
                                   a/ read x->regB=0
                                   b/ regB--=-1 
                                   c/ write regB->x=-1
 2/ regA++=1    
 3/ write regA->x=1
```

As all orders can be reached, the result will be \in{-1,0,1}

The only way to get a deterministic result is to use atomic read-modify-write instructions. All modern processors have means to do that (fetch-and-add or load-linked/store-cond), and in that case sequences 123 or abc cannot be split. The only possible ordering will be 123abc or abc123 and both will conduct to a deterministic result of x=0.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation makes sense and I finally was able to understand.